# jQuery focus() not quite working after first show() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a TextBox I want to move the focus to after showing it.  The problem is that on the initial `show()`, it will get focus during the show animation but it's gone after.  What's up?

It works fine in FireFox, but not IE8.  I have a running example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3PDLb/

Also, here is the code:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /><br />
<div id="Div1" style="display:none">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
</div>
<input id="Text2" type="text" />

$("#Text2").focus();

$("#Button1").click(function(){
    $("#Div1").toggle("slow").find("input:text").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question, but a workaround:

```
$("#Div1").toggle("slow", function(){$(this).find("input:text").focus()});
```